# Conversion of Strings like 'June 13, 7:23pm EDT' to Dates in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, string-to-datetime

My timestamp data looks like

```
June 13, 7:23pm EDT
```

The data is in string format. I need to convert it to

```
2023-6-13
```

Is there a way to do that? I am using BigQuery.

If I do:

```
select cast('June 13, 7:23pm EDT' as date);
```

I get this error:

```
Invalid date: 'June 13, 7:23pm EDT'
```

Comment: Cast/Convert it to date format .. here is how -->
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_functions

Answer (score 1):

Your cast query is correct but I believe the source timestamp formatting cannot match the cast's accepted format. The closest I can get is using parse_date function. But I have extracted the the date only using string manipulation(ragexp_contains) and extract the year to current date to full fill the formatting of the parse date paramter.

```
SELECT
  PARSE_DATE('%b %e %Y', CONCAT(REGEXP_EXTRACT('June 13, 7:23pm EDT', r'^(.*?),'), ' ', EXTRACT(YEAR
      FROM
        CURRENT_DATE()))) AS date
```

It is possible that there is a more optimal approach to this but here is the ouput of the query:

[image]